# How to check history of primary node in an Availability Group?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, high-availability, availability-groups

How do I see history of failovers of the primary node of a cluster? I'm trying to figure out at what point secondary node started to act as primary.

We are running Windows Server 2012 with SQL Server 2012 and Availability Groups.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's my go-to query to pull the events that Aaron mentioned (availability_replica_state_change).  This script also takes the liberty of converting the UTC time to your local time:

```
declare @xel_path varchar(1024);
declare @utc_adjustment int = datediff(hour, getutcdate(), getdate());

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------- target event_file path retrieval --------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;with target_data_cte as
(
    select  
        target_data = 
            convert(xml, target_data)
    from sys.dm_xe_sessions s
    inner join sys.dm_xe_session_targets st
    on s.address = st.event_session_address
    where s.name = 'alwayson_health'
    and st.target_name = 'event_file'
),
full_path_cte as
(
    select
        full_path = 
            target_data.value('(EventFileTarget/File/@name)[1]', 'varchar(1024)')
    from target_data_cte
)
select
    @xel_path = 
        left(full_path, len(full_path) - charindex('\', reverse(full_path))) + 
        '\AlwaysOn_health*.xel'
from full_path_cte;

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------- replica state change events -------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;with state_change_data as
(
    select
        object_name,
        event_data = 
            convert(xml, event_data)
    from sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file(@xel_path, null, null, null)
)
select
    object_name,
    event_timestamp = 
        dateadd(hour, @utc_adjustment, event_data.value('(event/@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime')),
    ag_name = 
        event_data.value('(event/data[@name = "availability_group_name"]/value)[1]', 'varchar(64)'),
    previous_state = 
        event_data.value('(event/data[@name = "previous_state"]/text)[1]', 'varchar(64)'),
    current_state = 
        event_data.value('(event/data[@name = "current_state"]/text)[1]', 'varchar(64)')
from state_change_data
where object_name = 'availability_replica_state_change'
order by event_timestamp desc;
```

Comment: Results correspond the what I got using another query, this is just a little bit easier to read and understand what it's doing.

Comment: What is the meaning of the state change events?

Answer (score 2):

Look for `availability_replica_state_change` events in the `AlwaysOn_health` extended events session. If this session is not running:

```
ALTER EVENT SESSION AlwaysOn_health ON SERVER WITH (STARTUP_STATE = ON);
ALTER EVENT SESSION AlwaysOn_health ON SERVER STATE = START;
```

More info:

- [New AlwaysOn_health Extended Events Session in SQL Server 2012 RC0](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/new-alwayson_health-extended-events-session-in-sql-server-2012-rc0/)
- [Answering Questions with the AlwaysOn Dashboard](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/joe/answering-questions-with-the-alwayson-dashboard/)
- [Monitoring Availability Groups Part 3 – Extended Events](http://tracyboggiano.com/archive/2017/07/monitoring-availability-groups-part-3-extended-events/)
- [AlwaysOn Extended Events](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn135324(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: Could you advise specifically what in the `availability_replica_state_change` needs checking?

Answer (score 2):

I used the following query that I got from [EXCHANGE SPILL](http://swasheck.wordpress.com/2013/08/08/when-did-my-availability-group-change-primary-replica-states/), but slightly modified it to convert time from UTC to local.

```
DECLARE @FileName NVARCHAR(4000)
SELECT @FileName = target_data.value('(EventFileTarget/File/@name)[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
    FROM (
           SELECT CAST(target_data AS XML) target_data
            FROM sys.dm_xe_sessions s
            JOIN sys.dm_xe_session_targets t
                ON s.address = t.event_session_address
            WHERE s.name = N'AlwaysOn_health'
         ) ft;

WITH    base
          AS (
               SELECT XEData.value('(event/@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime2(3)') AS event_timestamp
                   ,XEData.value('(event/data/text)[1]', 'VARCHAR(255)') AS previous_state
                   ,XEData.value('(event/data/text)[2]', 'VARCHAR(255)') AS current_state
                   ,ar.replica_server_name
                FROM (
                       SELECT CAST(event_data AS XML) XEData
                           ,*
                        FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file(@FileName, NULL, NULL, NULL)
                        WHERE object_name = 'availability_replica_state_change'
                     ) event_data
                JOIN sys.availability_replicas ar
                    ON ar.replica_id = XEData.value('(event/data/value)[5]', 'VARCHAR(255)')
             )
    SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), event_timestamp) AS event_timestamp
           ,previous_state
           ,current_state
           ,replica_server_name
        FROM base
        ORDER BY event_timestamp DESC;
```